# Error: Call to a member function getAuthor() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony

Am using symfony2 and doctrine2. When I try to recover the Author property from the Article entity using method getAutho(), it throws this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getAuthor() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\Portofolio\src\Portofolio\FrontBundle\Controller\FrontController.php line 65
```

This is my function:

```
public function showAction($slug) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //retrieve the the article using it's id
    $article = $em->getRepository('PortofolioAdminBundle:Article')->getArticleBySlug($slug);
    var_dump($article->getAuthor());
    //get About entity
    $about = $em->getRepository('PortofolioAdminBundle:About')->findOneBy(array('email' => 'baccouch.taieb@gmail.com'));
    //get all categories
    $categories = $em->getRepository('PortofolioAdminBundle:Category')->findAll();
    $articles = $em->getRepository('PortofolioAdminBundle:Article')->getLatestArticles();
    //create the search form
    $search = new Search();
    $searchForm = $this->createForm(new SearchType(), $search);
    return $this->render('PortofolioFrontBundle:Front:show.html.twig', array(
                'article' => $article, 'about' => $about, 'categories' => $categories,
                'articles' => $articles, 'searchForm' => $searchForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: The issue is the `$article` isn't being returned properly. Check for the value of the `$article` variable and see if it's an object or if the article isn't found.

Comment: yes, you are right. I had to change `getResults()` to `getSingleResult()` and the problem is fixed. Thank you @Davivd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in database there is no article with given slug so repository returns NULL.
Please check if incomming slug exists in articles table by using database client for your database engine.

You should also handle that kind of situation in your code. Please check symfony docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-errors-and-404-pages